# TSQL Queryto get Counts using Joins

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a very simple query I am using to get two separate counts. The issue I am running into is that with the join, I am getting skewed numbers which aren't accurate.

Is there a better way to get two separate counts from different tables?

```
SELECT   g.[group] AS groupName,
         COUNT(d.departmentDesc) AS total,
         COUNT(skg.Skillset) AS totalSkillsets
FROM     dbo.TFS_Groups AS g
         LEFT OUTER JOIN
         TFS_Departments_Groups AS d
         ON g.[group] = d.tfsGroup
         LEFT OUTER JOIN
         TFS_Skillsets_Groups AS skg
         ON skg.tfsGroup = g.[Group]
GROUP BY g.[group]
ORDER BY groupName ASC;
```

Comment: I see you've already got a couple of guessers, but for anyone to be sure they are helping you, you'll need to provide sample data and desired results.   "Skewed numbers" could be a lot of things.

Comment: @SBB, did either of the answers work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're after unique values you can put DISTINCT inside your COUNTs.
i.e.

```
SELECT   g.[group] AS groupName,
         COUNT(DISTINCT d.departmentDesc) AS total,
         COUNT(DISTINCT skg.Skillset) AS totalSkillsets
...
```

I suspect the issue is that you have two one to many relationships that are causing extra rows.

A way of reducing this would be to pre-aggregate in sub-queries i.e.

```
SELECT   g.[group] AS groupName,
         d.vol AS total,
         skg.vol AS totalSkillsets

FROM     dbo.TFS_Groups AS g

         LEFT OUTER JOIN
         (SELECT tfsgroup, count(*) as Vol 
         FROM   TFS_Skillsets_Groups
         group by tfsgroup) AS skg
         ON skg.tfsGroup = g.[Group]

         LEFT OUTER JOIN
         (SELECT tfsgroup, count(*) as Vol 
         FROM   TFS_Departments_Groups 
         group by tfsgroup) AS d
         ON d.tfsGroup = g.[Group]

ORDER BY groupName ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `APPLY`:

```
SELECT   g.[group] AS groupName,
         ca1.c1 AS total,
         ca2.c2 AS totalSkillsets
FROM     dbo.TFS_Groups AS g
OUTER APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*) AS c1 FROM TFS_Departments_Groups AS d WHERE g.[group] = d.tfsGroup) ca1
OUTER APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*) AS c2 FROM TFS_Skillsets_Groups AS skg WHERE g.[group] = skg.tfsGroup) ca2
```